# Does C# compiler optimize empty statements

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I have seen alot of questions about empty statements in C#

```
      string retVal="mystring";;
```

My question is:  If we don't remove the empty statements, will the compiler remove them in the optimization phases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can see this for yourself by compiling the application with and without empty statements, and checking the md5 checksum on the compiled application.

Comment: +1... but using Reflector, ILSpy, etc is probably a better way to "prove" to yourself that the empty statements have been removed. MD5 sum could change due to changes not necessarily related to the empty statements.

Answer (score 5):

Empty statements (like the one you cited), usually are recognized by the parser and never even make it into the abstract syntax tree.

So yes, they are absolutely removed.

Comment: I like this answer the best, the parser eliminates it, so the compiler never even sees it. This occurs regardless of whether you have optimization turned on or off; in this case, it is not even a function of the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, since the semicolon is just syntax. It simply tells the parser where the statement ends. The parser will strip "empty statements" much like unneeded whitespace is stripped by the lexer.

Comment: eek...scratch the "much like it strips whitespace". Whitespace is stripped by the lexer, empty statements by the parser, and needless statements (like `if(false) { ... }`) by an optimization step. Subtle distinction.